# Merging libreoffice spreadsheets into a multi-sheet document in headless mode?

Tags: linux, bash, libreoffice

We have an expensive report our system generates as XLS files, but when we try and run it for a whole year we run into memory issues on the responsible server.

I'd like to explore the idea of using libreoffice to combine multiple monthly reports into one spreadsheet that has tabs for Jan, Feb, Mar etc.

Is there a way to do this at the command line? Ideally it would take a directory of files called jan.xls, feb.xls etc and output a year.xls at the end.

Any help / pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: How much memory does your server have? How big are your files? Have you tried running it on the cloud (high memory high cpu EC2 instance?)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write a (bunch of) LibreOffice macro(s), and calling them from the command-line.

Here are what you need to do that:

- [How do I run a LibreOffice macro from the command line without the GUI?](https://superuser.com/questions/1135850/how-do-i-run-a-libreoffice-macro-from-the-command-line-without-the-gui)
- [OpenOffice.org Macros Explained](http://www.pitonyak.org/OOME_3_0.pdf) (Check pages 497-498)